# Similarity of matrices in SU(2)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have two matrices U,V in SU(2) such that U = SVS* for some matrix S in SU(2) and S* denote conjugate-transpose of the matrix.What is the easiest way to find S given V and U.

Comment: Are their diagonal matrix always equal?

Comment: You assumed they are equivalent, so they have the same characteristic equation, determinant, and trace. So they diagonalize to the same matrix.

Comment: Thanks @Cosmas Zachos

Comment: Is Tr(U) = Tr(V) a sufficient condition to prove U and V are similar,given U,V belongs to SU(2) ?

Comment: Actually yes. They have the same characteristic equation, and eigenvalues, so the respective projectors onto these relate them. see answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Diagonalize $U$, so $TUT^\dagger=D$, for some unitary $T$.

It then follows that 
$$
V=S^\dagger U S=S^\dagger T^\dagger  D TS,
$$
so $$ TSVS^\dagger T^\dagger =D \equiv RVR^\dagger,$$ likewise.

So, diagonalizing *U* with *T* and *V* with *R* and equating their diagonal forms *D* yields $S=R^\dagger T$.